# In search of some guidance regarding HashMap

Tags: java, static, hashmap, sudoku

I'm making a Sudoku Solver program in Java, which uses backtracking and bruteforce for the solving algorithm. The problem I seem to be having is that when I insert the correct values in a simple container, the wrong values are showing when i try to access it from another class.

HashMap has the correct values in the correct locations when I print it out from inside the insert method in `Sudokucontainer`, (with a `for(int i = 0 i < dim; i++) + for(int j = 0; j < dim; j++)`) followed by `Square[][] tmp = solutionsHash.get(count)` and `System.out.println(tmp[i][j].getValue());`. It's also successful when I use the same for-loops right after the `solutions.insert` statement in the `Square` class' `fillInnRemainingOfBoard()` (followed by `Square[][] tmp = solutions.solutionsHash.get(count)` and the same `System.out.println` statement.

The problem occurs when I try to do the same from the `Board` class, as you can see in my test() method in that class. Then it just prints out the predefined values(or nothing if the board is empty). The only difference is that I then use i.e. `Square[][] tmp = allSquares[0][0].solutionsHash.get(wantedNumber)` and the same as before. But as I mentioned, I don't see why that should make a difference, when `solutionsHash` are declared static in the `Sudokucontainer`-class.

Any help is greatly appriciated. Thanks!

**NOTE:** The indentation got screwed up somehow, sorry about that. I haven't included the GUI part because I haven't written that and I possibly don't have permission to put it on here. Also the problem occurs before that(possibly in the `Board` class), as the same values are printed out there as from the `Board` class.

**EDIT:** Removed some unnecessary code.

```
public class Square {

static Sudokucontainer solutions;
protected char value;
protected int valueInt;
protected static Square allSquares[][];
public int count = 0;
protected boolean predefined = false;
protected boolean lastSquare = false;
protected Square next = null;


public void setNext() {
if(col.getNr() < col.dim) {
    next = allSquares[row.getNr()-1][col.getNr()];
}else if(col.getNr() == col.dim) {
    if(row.getNr() < row.dim) {
    next = allSquares[row.getNr()][0];
    }else {
    next = null;
    lastSquare = true;
    }
}
if(next != null) {
    if(next.col.getNr() == col.dim && next.row.getNr() == col.dim && next.predefined == true)
    lastSquare = true;
}
}
public void fillInnRemainingOfBoard(Square[][] allSquares, int hd, int br) { 

    this.allSquares = allSquares;
int highestNumber = col.dim;
setNext();

if(value == '\u0020') {
    for(int i = 1; i <= highestNumber; i++) {
    if(row.isLegal[i-1] && col.isLegal[i-1] && box.isLegal[i-1]) { 
        String s1 = Integer.toString(i);
        value = s1.charAt(0);
        insert(value);
        insertInt(i);
        box.isLegal[i-1] = false;
        col.isLegal[i-1] = false;
        row.isLegal[i-1] = false;
        if(!lastSquare) {
        next.fillInnRemainingOfBoard(this.allSquares, hd, br);
        }else{   
        System.out.println("Solution found: " + count);
        solutions.insert(allSquares, count, col.dim);
        ++count;
        } // Slutt paa else 
        box.isLegal[valueInt-1] = true;
        col.isLegal[valueInt-1] = true;
        row.isLegal[valueInt-1] = true;
        value = '\u0020';
        } // Slutt paa if(row.isLegal[i-1] && col.isLegal[i-1] && box.isLegal[i-1])     
    } // Slutt paa if (value == '\u0020' || !predefined) 
}else {     
    if(!lastSquare) {
    next.fillInnRemainingOfBoard(this.allSquares, hd, br);
    } else {
    System.out.println("Solution found");
    solutions.insert(allSquares, count, col.dim);
    count++;
    }
} // Slutt paa else if(predefined)      
// Slutt paa for(int i = 1; i <= highestNumber; i++)
}// Her returnerer vi til forrige metode

public void insert(char value) {
if(value != '.') {
    this.value = value;

}else{
    this.value = '\u0020'; // In other words; space(in unicode)
}
}

public void insertInt(int value) {
valueInt = value;
}



public char getValue() {
return value;
}

}

public class Sudokucontainer {  

int dim = 0;
private int count = 0;
static HashMap<Integer, Square[][]> solutionsHash = new HashMap<Integer, Square[][]>();

public void insert(Square[][] allSquares, int count, int dim) {
this.count = count;
this.dim = dim;

if(count <= 499) {
    solutionsHash.put(count,allSquares);
}

}

public Square[][] get(int nr) {
Square[][] tmp = solutionsHash.get(nr);
return tmp;
}

public int getSolutionCount() {
return solutionsHash.size();
}

}

public class Board {

int dim, br, hd;
char[][] charArray;
char[] charArray1;
static Square [][] allSquares; 
Row [] rows;
Column[] columns;
Box[] boxes;

    public Board(int dim, int br, int hd, char[][] charArray) {
this.dim = dim;
this.br = br;
this.hd = hd;
this.charArray = charArray;
charArray1 = new char[dim];
allSquares = new Square[dim][dim];
rows = new Row[dim];
columns = new Column[dim];
boxes = new Box[dim/br * dim/hd];
setRows();
setColumns();
setBoxes();
setSquares();
insertBoxInSquares();
fillInLegalValues();
welcome();
solve();
test();
System.out.println("Found solutions. Please refer to the graphical interface.");
showGui();


}


public void test() { 
    for(int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
        //Square[][] tmp = allSquares[0][0].solutions.solutionsHash.get(0);
        //System.out.println(tmp[i][j].getValue());
        }
    }
}

public void solve() {

allSquares[0][0].fillInnRemainingOfBoard(allSquares, hd, br);

}

public void showGui() {
new SudokuGUI(dim, hd, br, allSquares[0][0].solutions.solutions, false, 0, allSquares[0][0].solutions.solutionsHash);
}

}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code.

Comment: I'll try to remove some unnecessary code.

Comment: @user2291525 : that would help if you remove unnecessary code

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow; the question still contains a pretty large chunk of code.  You're more likely to get helpful feedback if you can narrow the problem down to a much smaller area.

Comment: Thanks ASGM, and thanks for fixing the code some so it looks better on this site! I'll try, but I'm afraid I may remove something that's useful for finding the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can tell you what the problem is, though not what causes it.

You are either printing out different objects, or the object's values are changing between one print and another.  You can identify an object by printing either its hashcode or a toString()  call on the object, and therefore tell whether it is the same object in different cases.

If they're different, I would check that you aren't loading up an object with a temporary scope in one case and printing out one with a bigger scope in the next case.  But it's also possible you're just referring to a different object; I cannot tell what's going on from the code you posted, it is possible you got confused yourself.

Your post's title is the reason I say this.  It is just not feasible that the "values in [the] hashmap are not correct".  When one is fairly new to programming, and sometimes for years afterwards, half of debugging is believing that (1) the programming language constructs really do work as advertised, and (2) you screwed up somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @rcook. The object's seemed to be the same according to the hashcode. I can't seem to grasp why this happened, and even though I think it's interesting looking for the solution I don't have time for it right now. So I went with another solution(3D array). Still is a mystery for me though, because I used the same procedure for the array(as far as I can see anyway), but that worked like a charm.

You're totally right that the title is misleading/wrong. If it's possible I'll change it. Thanks again.